# adding in an array as a single element of Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to put an array as a single element of a pandas Dataframe.  I am searching for the indices using two conditions, so my syntax is something like

```
element=list([a, b])
df.loc[(col1=='a')&(col2=='b'),'col3']=element
```

From reading other stack exchange posts and from past experience I think this should work.  However I am getting the error

```
Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

which I don't get when using a single element, like 0.  Why doesn't this work?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide entire or at least part of your dataframe (not an image) and show us an expected output :)

Answer (score 1):

If you try and assign a list to a DataFrame, Pandas will check that the list is the same length as the number of rows, that is the error you are seeing. To assign a list to a DataFrame you will need to provide a list of lists, with the outer list being the same length as the DataFrame and the inner list being the data you would like to assign.

In your example, the following should work:

```py
element=list([a, b])
df.loc[(col1=="a")&(col2=="b"), "col3"] = [element for row in df[(col1=="a")&(col2=="b")]]
```

Note that the assigned list is the same length as the filtered DataFrame.